# Map words to numbers

Tags: cryptography, information-retrieval

I am doing indexing of data in my IRE (Information Retrieval and Extraction) course. Now instead of storing terms in the index, I am storing termID which is a mapping corresponding to the term. The size of term, if the length of the term is 15, would be 15 bytes i.e. 120 bits while if I use termID instead of term then I can definitely store it in less than 120 bits. One of the possible ways is to maintain a dictionary of the (term, termID) where termID would be from 1..n where n is the number of terms. The problems with this method is:

1. I have to keep this dictionary in the ram and the dictionary size can be in GBs.
2. To find termID corresponding to a term, it will take O(log(n)) where n is the number of terms in the dictionary.

Can I make some function which takes a term as an input and returns the mapping (encryption) in O(1) ?. It is okay if there are few collisions (Just guessing that a few collisions in exchange of speed and memory is a good trade-off. BTW I don't know how much it will effect my search results).

Is there any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you gave the answer already more or less by saying "it is ok if there are a few collisions". The trick is hashing. You can first reduce the number of "characters" in your search terms. E.g., drop numbers, and special characters. Afterwards you can merge Upper and lower-case characters. Finally you could apply some simple replacements e.g. replacing the german ü bei ue (which is actually there origin). After doing so you have probably sth. like 32bit. You can then represent an four character string in a single byte. If you reserve 4 bytes for each words you need to deal with the longer words. There you can basically resort to `xor` each 4byte block.

An alternative approach would be to do something hybrid for the dictionary. If you would build a dictionary for only the 10k most frequent words you are most likely covering already most of the texts. Hence, you only need to keep parts of your dictionary in memory, while for most of the words you can use dictionary on hardisc or maybe even ignore them.